# rviz doesn't launch --> core dumped

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

When I execute the command line "rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find stage_ros`/rviz/stage.rviz" I get the following error:

```
OpenGL Warning: No pincher, please call crStateSetCurrentPointers() in your SPU
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I may note that I am using the Hydro distribution on a Ubuntu 12.04 on VirtualBox with 3D hardware acceleration enabled, but it seems that still there is a problem with graphics ... .
I haven't been able to find any solution to the problem by surfing on the Internet. I really need your help as I'm doing a project and I'm stuck badly. How can I solve this error?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145601/rviz-doesn%27t-launch---%3E-core-dumped/) by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't look like a ROS problem, it's a VirtualBox problem I believe.

Which version of VirtualBox are you using? Maybe you should update to the latest.

---

Originally posted by [nanaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/5617/nanaky/) with karma: 23 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on 2014-03-28**:
I'm using v. 4.3.6. I am going to update it to the latest.

**Comment by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) on 2014-03-28**:
The problem still persists :(

**Comment by [nanaky](https://answers.ros.org/users/5617/nanaky/) on 2014-03-28**:
Try deselecting the 3D accelerator box in Display in the VBox Manager.

**Comment by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on 2017-06-07**:
Yes, exactly go to the virtual machine settings in your VirtualBox control panel and deselect the "Enable 3D acceleration"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I had to install Ubuntu besides Windows. As far as I found out, for new graphic cards VirtualBox does not offer good 3D hardware acceleration service!
So, I had to install Ubuntu. The problem is solved and rviz runs smoothly.

---

Originally posted by [Warrior](https://answers.ros.org/users/11476/warrior/) with karma: 61 on 2014-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1